# Problema al usar python 3.7.5 en heroku

Tags: python-3.7, heroku

Bueno mi problema esta bien explicado en el titulo, quiero iniciar una app escrita en python en heroku pero me dice que python 3.7.5 no esta disponible para este stack ( heroku-18 ), pero en la [pagina](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support) dice que python 3.7.5 esta disponible para todo los stacks asi que por eso pregunto por aca si a alguien le paso algo similar y como lo soluciono

```
(Blog) frijol@frijolito:~/Blog/blog$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 149, done.
Counting objects: 100% (149/149), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (111/111), done.
Writing objects: 100% (149/149), 7.35 MiB | 1.75 MiB/s, done.
Total 149 (delta 37), reused 125 (delta 31)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Requested runtime (Python 3.7.6) is not available for this stack (heroku-18).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to obscure-lowlands-90011.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/obscure-lowlands-90011.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/obscure-lowlands-90011.git'
```

esa es la salida despues de hacer el `git push`

Comment: Revisa esta parte de la documentación: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#selecting-a-runtime

Comment: @fredyfx OMG soy imbécil, leí esa parte y cambie el espacio por un guion pero no me fije en la mayúscula jajaja, muchas gracias <3

Comment: deja publico la respuesta :D

Answer (score 1):

Para especificar un runtime de Python, agrega un documento llamado `runtime.txt` en el directorio root de tu aplicación, dicho archivo tiene que contener la versión exacta para usar:

```
cat runtime.txt
python-3.7.5
```

Mayor información en la documentación oficial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#selecting-a-runtime